# Objective-c share image and text

Tags: objective-c, share

I want to share image and text in my iOS app. I have 4 buttons (Facebook,Twitter,Pinterest,Google+). I want to share in related app . How can i do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

iOS has an inbuilt social sharing kit. You can share images via Facebook and Twitter. But for using Google+ & Pinterest you will need their SDKs.

**Social.Framework** header files

```
#import <Social/Social.h>
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>
```

**For Facebook** :

```
SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];        
[controller setInitialText:message];
[controller addImage:image];
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];
```

**For Twitter** :

```
replace SLServiceTypeFacebook with SLServiceTypeTwitter.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to ask one more question. Can i get info of  user who shares the image?

Comment: SLComposeViewController through share image & text only. if i have login in my device with Facebook then that post share to my account. if you get user info then you must use particular SDK.

Comment: Okay, I understand. Thanks again.